# Does debug info deserves to be translated?

Tags: python-2.7, localization, internationalization, translation, globalization

I know. Maybe this question isn't in its correspondig area, but as long it's linked with programming (In this case, python2.7), it seems quite logical to me to post it here...

In fact, That's the main question.

***Should it be necessary to translate debug info to other languages?***

It's quite a trivial question, but it's something I've faced recently, and I don't know if I should do it or not.

P.S: By "Debug Info" I refer to text like "[TimeStamp] Handshake completed!" or "[TimeStamp] Download progress: %64"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would base the answer on the following simple question: Is the information to be interpreted by the end user (→ translate) or by the developer (→ don't translate).

Normally, debug messages fall squarely into the second category (if they don't, it might be worth looking at the UI design) – but that's for you to decide.

Even if it is the end user who will be expected to relay debug messages to the developers, I would refrain from translating them as long as the user is not expected to interpret and act based on the *content* of the messages. This will simplify both the localisation (and localisation update) process and, perhaps more importantly, the interpretation of user-submitted logs.

Comment: Welp...It's kind of funny that, now that I've made all the pertinent modifications to my program, I decide to come back here to read any possible answers, xD. In fact, I decided to translate the whole program, for the sake of internationalization. Why? As you said, IN CASE that someone feels able to understand debug info and he/she is going to contact a dev, or (If possble) will try to modify source code,in this way, maybe he/she is going to receive info in a more "direct" way,rather than translating the message and,if you want to,unsetting LANG environment variable should reset all to english

Comment: @PythonNoob, externalising all your messages is not a bad idea in itself, even if you choose not to localise all of them. You could still separate the debug-related messages from UI messages so that localisers can give priority to the UI first (if the debug messages make up a significant proportion, otherwise it's not worth the bother). And later on, you could file a field report back here about your experience with localised debug messages :).

Comment: As I said to @Miro Krsjak,my app has a "Console" mode and a "Graphic" mode. It's intended to be kinda "bullet-proof" (E.G: Dependendies not met? or GTK3 too slow for u? maybe got no graphic card and you're on tty1?) If on "Console" mode,all debug info goes redirected to a file. If on "Graphic" mode, debug output goes directly to console.So all "debug" info and related isn't too visible as GUI info, so translators will focus in GUI first.

Comment: @PythonNoob "so translators will focus in GUI first" - All too often I see strings dumped for localisation that are in no particular order (or sometimes even worse: sorted alphabetically by content J). If your strings are separated and/or sorted by category, translators can indeed prioritise and everything's fine.

Comment: :D But of course! My main priority was that, indeed. Strings are organized by category and subcategories. E.G (en_US -> GUI -> Settings -> Advanced Settings -> stringTurnOffNotifications = "Turn off notifications?" // es_ES -> Console -> Messages -> Debug -> stringStatusNotifications = "Estado actual de las notificaciones: "

Answer (score 2):

It simply depends on the information of who is the debug info for?
In case of devs only, any dev should know english I think.
In case of end users and a multilanguage app, it might be worth the translation. But what are the endusers gonna do with the debug info anyway?
In case of multicultural large project, it might be useful, but my experience, we always agree on a common dev language and that includes debug info.

Comment: Most of it it's true, but, if we take semi-common info as examples, like download progress, or when GUI found a file and it just reports it on console too (With debug option enabled for both), would it deserve translations?

Comment: My opinion no. User dont watch consoles, unless support makes them and any info for a user should be in his UI. If he's destined to see upload progress, should be visible. Is this a web app or console or desktop?

Comment: Desktop App. In fact, the GUI has full translations support, so anybody can translate its strings in his/her language and send me a "template" file with all translated strings, to just merge it in its source code.

The main reason to ask this was my idea to bring 100% translation support to my App, no matter if you're using it in "GUI" mode, or just in console

Comment: Simply ask yourself and the team, imagine the future, if it will be common that the user needs to read the log. If yes, do it.

Comment: LOL, in case of console mode and debug mode would log info always even in user mode, the users would be unhappy to read strange text so yes. In case you need a flag to enable debug logs, so they are not shown in normal runs, I would lean to no.

Comment: You can also look at cost of implementation, is it so easy you can do it anyway? The go for it. If it brings more effort, its worth to discuss it with the team for example.

Comment: Oh no, when "console" mode in on, all debug info is redirected to a file, for latter inspection, if needed, but the "normal" info displayed in "console" mode isn't translated like the one shown in "GUI" mode, due to some limitations in the order I coded my program.

In case I decide to support translations in both log and console mode, I would need to rewrite at least 75% of my program, if not all (Don't blame me, I'm recovering an old proyect of mine I left time ago, when I as starting in python, xD)

P.S: I hope I'm not bothering too much, :D

Comment: Then evaluate the usage of that log by the users. If not used actively and you have other priorities, put this into the backlog ;)

Comment: Umm, seems logical...
Well, then I suppose I'll archive that in my "to-do" list. It would be an interesting feature, tough...
Thanks for your time asking to my (useless?) question!
P.S: I'm don't have a team with/behind me, It's only me, :D (So I decide everything about my App ¬.¬)